# CVI Project to Visual Studio Project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cvi

I'm trying to move a project from LabWindows/CVI 9 to Visual studio, I've been correcting errors by importing cvi libraries, now I've run into this error, but I can't find where the library comes from and it seems to be the last one I'm missing

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function _WinMain@16 MES_Control_2.0.3.39    cviwmain.lib(extwmain.obj)

in the case of the other libraries it gave the same error but now I can't find extwmain.c or extwmain.lib

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your project already is configured to link `cviwmain.lib`. The error means it needs a `main()` function. You probably configured your project as a windows application(not a console application), so just remove that library because you don't need it. See [this documentation](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labwindows-cvi/page/cvi/usermanual/prjbldmenuextcomplrspt.htm) for detail.